# Car Racing Game

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am currently working on a Car Racing Web game using HTML, CSS and JavaScript.

My work is about to over but I am facing a problem in the game. Let me tell you about the game, there are two cars i.e. White Car and Red Car on a Canvas Element.

The white car is controlled using up, down, left and right arrow keys and the red car is controlled using WASD keys.

**My problem is: If I move the white car the red car gets hidden and if i move the red car the white car gets hidden.**

The Code is Given Below:

```
<html>
    <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="project84.css">
      <title>Car Racing Game</title>
      <style>

body {
  background-image: url("https://i.postimg.cc/KzWwHPcq/racing.gif");
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
}

#myCanvas {
  margin-top: 30px;
  border-width: 10px;
  background-color: white;
  border-style: ridge;
  border-color: #5e5e5e;
}

h1,
h4 {
  color: white !important;
}
#myDiv{
  background-color: black;
  width: 250px;
  border: 2px white ridge;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

</style>
    </head>
    <body onload="add();">
      <center>
        <h1>Car Racing Game</h1>
        <span>
          <h2>Game Status: </h2>
          <h2 id="game_status" class="text-danger"></h2>
        </span>
        <canvas id="myCanvas" height="500px" width="700px"></canvas>
        <h4>
          <b class="text-danger">NOTE : </b> IF THE CARS ARE NOT VISIBLE PRESS ANY ARROW KEY
          <br>
          <b class="text-danger">*Please Click once on the car before pressing any Arrow Key</b>
          <br><br>
          <div id="myDiv">
            Arrow Keys for White Car
            <br>
            WASD Keys for Red Car
          </div>
        </h4>
      </center>
      <script>
canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

car1_width = 100;
car1_height = 90;

car2_width = 102;
car2_height = 90;

background_img = "https://i.postimg.cc/bv5d35nK/racing.jpg";

car1_img = "https://i.postimg.cc/YqdnnNX1/car1.png";

car2_img =
  "https://www.seekpng.com/png/full/397-3971125_car-clipart-top-view.png";

car1_x = 10;
car1_y = 10;

car2_x = 10;
car2_y = 105;

function add() {
  background_imgTag = new Image();
  background_imgTag.onload = uploadBackground;
  background_imgTag.src = background_img;

  car1_imgTag = new Image();
  car1_imgTag.onload = uploadCar1;
  car1_imgTag.src = car1_img;

  car2_imgTag = new Image();
  car2_imgTag.onload = uploadCar2;
  car2_imgTag.src = car2_img;
}

function uploadBackground() {
  ctx.drawImage(background_imgTag, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}

function uploadCar1() {
  ctx.drawImage(car1_imgTag, car1_x, car1_y, car1_width, car1_height);
}

function uploadCar2() {
  ctx.drawImage(car2_imgTag, car2_x, car2_y, car2_width, car2_height);
}

window.addEventListener("keydown", my_keydown);

function my_keydown(e) {
  keyPressed = e.keyCode;
  console.log(keyPressed);
  // arrow key code
  if (keyPressed == "38") {
    up();
    console.log("up");
  }
  if (keyPressed == "40") {
    down();
    console.log("down");
  }
  if (keyPressed == "37") {
    left();
    console.log("left");
  }
  if (keyPressed == "39") {
    right();
    console.log("right");
  }
  // W A S D code
  if (keyPressed == "87") {
    up1();
    console.log("W");
  }
  if (keyPressed == "83") {
    down1();
    console.log("S");
  }
  if (keyPressed == "65") {
    left1();
    console.log("A");
  }
  if (keyPressed == "68") {
    right1();
    console.log("D");
  }
}
// functions for arrow keys
function up() {
  if (car1_y >= 0) {
    car1_y = car1_y - 10;
    console.log("When up arrow is pressed, x = " + car1_x + " | y = " + car1_y);
    uploadBackground();
    uploadCar1();
  }
}

function down() {
  if (car1_y <= 500) {
    car1_y = car1_y + 10;
    console.log(
      "When down arrow is pressed, x = " + car1_x + " | y = " + car1_y
    );
    uploadBackground();
    uploadCar1();
  }
}

function left() {
  if (car1_x >= 0) {
    car1_x = car1_x - 10;
    console.log(
      "When left arrow is pressed, x = " + car1_x + " | y = " + car1_y
    );
    uploadBackground();
    uploadCar1();
  }
}

function right() {
  if (car1_x <= 700) {
    car1_x = car1_x + 10;
    console.log(
      "When right arrow is pressed, x = " + car1_x + " | y = " + car1_y
    );
    uploadBackground();
    uploadCar1();
  }
  if (car1_x >= 600) {
    console.log("White Car Won!");
    document.getElementById("game_status").innerHTML = "White Car Won!";
  }
}
// functions for W A S D
function up1() {
  if (car2_y >= 0) {
    car2_y = car2_y - 10;
    console.log("When up arrow is pressed, x = " + car2_x + " | y = " + car2_y);
    uploadBackground();
    uploadCar2();
  }
}

function down1() {
  if (car2_y <= 500) {
    car2_y = car2_y + 10;
    console.log(
      "When down arrow is pressed, x = " + car2_x + " | y = " + car2_y
    );
    uploadBackground();
    uploadCar2();
  }
}

function left1() {
  if (car2_x >= 0) {
    car2_x = car2_x - 10;
    console.log(
      "When left arrow is pressed, x = " + car2_x + " | y = " + car2_y
    );
    uploadBackground();
    uploadCar2();
  }
}

function right1() {
  if (car2_x <= 700) {
    car2_x = car2_x + 10;
    console.log(
      "When right arrow is pressed, x = " + car2_x + " | y = " + car2_y
    );
    uploadBackground();
    uploadCar2();
  }
  if (car2_x >= 600) {
    console.log("Red Car Won!");
    document.getElementById("game_status").innerHTML = "Red Car Won!";
  }
}

      </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

For output, click the link below:

https://codepen.io/RiYad06/pen/yLMpvLg

Comment: You haven't mentioned anywhere what the specific problem or question is

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) + [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) - Just go through _your_ code and check the steps it does when you "move a car", e.g. what happens with the "background"?

Comment: Not sure why people were complaining, the issue was pretty clear in the original post (even before it got reformatted), and got 2 answers. It was actually pretty good for a first time user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to invoke upload on 2 cars in the move functions like this:

```
function up() {
  if (car1_y >= 0) {
    car1_y = car1_y - 10;
    console.log("When up arrow is pressed, x = " + car1_x + " | y = " + car1_y);
    uploadBackground();
    uploadCar1();
    uploadCar2();
  }
}
```

https://codepen.io/lrazerz/pen/abJGBeY

Answer (score 0):

You need to render all your objects every time.

So when you're handling for example `right()`, you still need to draw the second car.

```
 function right() {
  if (car1_x <= 700) {
    car1_x = car1_x + 10;
    console.log(
      "When right arrow is pressed, x = " + car1_x + " | y = " + car1_y
    );
    uploadBackground();
    uploadCar1();
    uploadCar2(); // <<< YOU NEED THIS
  }
  if (car1_x >= 600) {
    console.log("White Car Won!");
    document.getElementById("game_status").innerHTML = "White Car Won!";
  }
}
```

You can create something like a `renderScene()` function that you can call in all your handler to avoid repeating yourself too much.